# Fourier transforms of two functions identical on bounded interval

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

It is known that sufficiently "well-behaved" functions admitting a Fourier transform are uniquely associated with it: two functions with identical Fourier transforms will be identical. But what happens if their Fourier transforms only coincide in some bounded set?

More in detail, let $f_1$, $f_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ continuous functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose Fourier transforms are equal in a bounded interval, say $[-\Omega,\Omega]$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\forall\omega\in[-\Omega,\Omega]:\quad\int_\mathbb{R}f_1(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_\mathbb{R}f_2(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
while possibly being different outside the interval. Can we say something about the relation between $f_1$ and $f_2$? Are they related somehow?

Comment: We can say that their difference has a Fourier transform vanishing on $[-\Omega, \Omega]$. Equivalently, $f_1$ and $f_2$ have identical convolutions with a particular sinc filter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter